# How to add database to HSQLDB server programmatically without restarting the server?

Tags: java, hsqldb, lan

As per the need of my java application,i am trying to add new database to the already running HSQLDB server. As i am new to HSQLDB, I just want to know,is it possible to add database to the server in such dynamic way ? all Suggestions to achieve this functionality are most welcome,thank you.

Comment: I need help please, as i am stuck with this point for LAN implementation.

Comment: Does this help: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/listeners-chapt.html#lsc_remote_open

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for your reply sir,i have tried it already but it is giving me exception as java.sql.SQLException: General error: database alias does not exist.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  now the error is java.sql.SQLException: General error: remote open not allowed

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your valuable guidence. It resolved my problem. Everything working perfectly now.Thank you once again.